# Filter out entire row based on one result in Tableau

Tags: tableau-desktop

Learning Tableau through tutorials so bear with me.

I have a list I need to filter, but when I set up a calculated field, it only filters out a single cell, not the whole row.

Here's the example I made:

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3Hgo.png)

In this table, I want to filter out entire rows that have negative values. Alice and Bob would be hidden, but Cat and Dee would remain.

When I add a (IF SCORE <0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) filter, I only filter out that single value, not the whole row. Example:

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AeKao.png)

How do I write a calc to hide the rows with negatives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry i cannot recreate your example, but i used one of my use cases.

just drag "name" to the filter pane and in the filter options go to conditions

there you need to apply the logic of Value > 0

[image: Condition]

This will make the rows disappear. Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for responding! This solution worked, with a tweak. Instead of (IF SUM>0), I used (IF MIN>0). SUM uses the grand total for that row, which is positive, but using the minimum filtered by any negative values as intended. Here's a screenshot in case someone finds this post in the future https://ibb.co/Gv2J9Fz

This is a much cleaner solution than what I've seen on the Tableau forums, thank you so much for posting!!